# python script to generate C++ header file from a CSV file (for array declaration)

Tags: python, c++

I am actually working on a python script that will use a CSV file to generate automatically a c++ header file that contains an array declaration.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Best regards,
Khalil

Comment: show us what have you tried so far

Comment: Reading about the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module might be a good starting point. And if that's not your problem, then please tell us *what* you have problems with, and show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a [module for reading csv files](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Once you understand how to read a csv line into a list, it's just a matter of printing the data the way you want:

```
# prolog
print('int myarray[] = {')

# data
for row in ...:
    for element in row:
        print('%d, ' % element)

# epilog
print('};')
```

you can redirect python's output to a file with `python myscript.py > output.h`